# How to integrate two angular js modules from two different servers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

We want to develop a angular js module for our application and want to integrate in other angular js app.
These apps renders from two different servers.

I have read about angular js multple modules and bootstraping them manually.
But in those examples, both the modules are from same server.

In our case, they are two different angular js applications.

The applications are like this. App1: /mainapplication App2: /secondapplication Both the modules may use different version of angularjs.

Please let me know if it is possible or not, if yes, what are the ways to integrate it.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is preventing you using them from different domains? Did you even try it?

Comment: I did not try the integration. But i want to understand how route configurations work. 
The applications are like this.


App1: <domain1.com>/mainapplication

App2: <domain2.com>/secondapplication

Both the modules may use different version of angularjs.

Comment: That depends on how your app is set up.

Comment: if the other module is independent , just include the file(use full URL with servername and port) into the other project using script tags and add as a dependency in the controllers

Answer (score 0):

Use bower to manage dependencies. Create a component in a angular module, include this dependency in both projects and add module to both apps.